# Not a member of type<type> in the currently loaded schema

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have query for EDM in the codebehind as below, searchString contains the text that should be searched.

```
context.Applicants.OrderBy("it." + sortExpression).Include("FSWorker").
Where("it.[CaseName] like '%'" + searchString + "'%'").ToList();
```

throwing an error 'ash' is not a member of type 'SCDSS_ApplicationDataModel.Applicant' in the currently loaded schemas. Near simple identifier, line 8, column 4.

Comment: The content of the string `sortExpression` is "ash". Maybe?

Comment: ash, was the search string that was entered in the page to search

Comment: And what is in `searchString` if searched string is in `sortExpression`?

Comment: searchString has the searched string, sortExpression has the column to be sorted on when retrieving the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you have spare single quotes on the inner side of your % symbols in the where clause ?

Comment: @inlokesh: Andiih means this: `...'%" + searchString + "%'"...` (only the *inner* single quotes are removed). This definitely compiles.

Comment: Thanks @Slauma, it compiles but it still get the same error when I use search on the page

Comment: @inlokesh: Did you debug the code and watched the content of `sortExpression` and `searchString`? It's impossible that this `Where("it.[CaseName] like '%ash%'")` is responsible for the error you've described in your question.

Comment: Thanks @Slauma, it works now, sortExpression and searchString were mixed up.

Comment: @inlokesh: You should nonetheless accept this as valid answer. Aside from the mixed strings removing the inner single quotes as suggested by Andiih was important as well to get this working.